# Asp.net ImageUrl Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, imageurl

this is definitely an easy question but I still don't know what exactly it is for. Can anybody tell me what `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'` means? I still don't get the idea why we need to include `%#`.

Comment: You shouldn't say "sorry", we all here for learning.

Comment: It's a database fieldname from which the URL (or source of image) will be set.

Answer (score 2):

`<%# Eval("FileName") %>` is used in the context of binding data from a collection to a control. Probably the value for the imageurl is coming from a property of an object in the collection

For example, `List<Photo>` where `Photo` has a property of `FileName`. If you are binding that to a gridview, a repeater, etc, you'll access that property for each item in the collection when binding to such controls

- [Asp.net data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

Comment: Thank you very much everybody. Now I understand everything about this.

Answer (score 2):

in this Line...

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'
```

ImageURL the attribute of your  asp:ImageButton control that is used to specify the Url of the Image File to be Used

Code between '<% and  %>' tags are writtent to be Executed on the Server

'#' is used to specify that the result of server side execution will be bound hear

Eval KeyWord is Used To Evaluate the perticular Column Value (that you specify ("--hear--")) from The DataSourse

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a Template Control like `Repeater` , `GridView` , etc. you are actually iterating in a list of data records, and `<%# Eval("FileName") %>` here means give me the value of the column named `FileName`.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have used the Eval function which is used for one way databinding. FileName is the field name you are associating. Anything that's written inside <%# %> is parsed by asp.net engine before generating the webpage source which is pure client side script and html tags.
So Eval function is executed at server end by ASP.net engine.